# String Date conversion in python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, datetime-format

I have a data frame with date in the format "Mar-97" and I want to convert it into "03-1997". The format of data is

```
     Month  SilverPrice GoldPrice
0   Mar-97  186.48  12619.24
1   Apr-97  170.65  12338.59
2   May-97  170.44  12314.94
3   Jun-97  169.96  12202.78
4   Jul-97  155.80  11582.07
```

I have written this code but it is converting it into "1997-03-01"

```
from datetime import datetime
df["Month"]=list(map(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,'%b-%y'),df["Month"]))
```

and the output is something like this

```
      Month SilverPrice GoldPrice
0   1997-03-01  186.48  12619.24
1   1997-04-01  170.65  12338.59
2   1997-05-01  170.44  12314.94
3   1997-06-01  169.96  12202.78
4   1997-07-01  155.80  11582.07
```

I can do it by stripping the day value but is there any direct way to convert it into the "MM-YYYY" format .

Answer (score 2):

#### [`pd.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

You can specify your `datetime` format via Python's [`strftime` directives](http://strftime.org/):

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month']).dt.strftime('%m-%Y')

print(df)

     Month  SilverPrice  GoldPrice
0  03-1997       186.48   12619.24
1  04-1997       170.65   12338.59
2  05-1997       170.44   12314.94
3  06-1997       169.96   12202.78
4  07-1997       155.80   11582.07
```

Comment: But it is giving this error  `ValueError: day is out of range for month`

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh : You are getting error because the Date column format is mixed up. "Mar-98" & "2-Sep" these two formats are present in that column. You can see this if you open excel. The solution for this is,                  
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Month"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%b-%y'))).dt.strftime('%m-%Y')

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

data = ['Mar-97',
        'Apr-97',
        'May-97',
        'Jun-97',
        'Jul-97']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Month'])
df["Month"] = list(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%b-%y').strftime('%m-%Y'), df["Month"]))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     Month
0  03-1997
1  04-1997
2  05-1997
3  06-1997
4  07-1997
```

Answer (score 0):

Date column format is mixed up in this data set. The two visible difference are "Mar-98" & "2-Sep". 
If you open in excel these two formats are visible.

```
The solution for this is, 

df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Month"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%b-%y'))).dt.strftime('%m-%Y')
```